# добавлять значения в ассоциативный массив динамически

Tags: php, javascript

имеется страница с полями вот код и скрин

```
<table class="table-bordered table-striped table">
      <tr>
        <th class="col-sm-2">Код товара</th>
        <th class="col-sm-5">Название</th>
        <th class="col-sm-2">Стомость, грн</th>
        <th class="col-sm-2">Количество, шт</th>
      </tr>
      <?php foreach ($itemsList as $item):?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $item['code']; ?></td><!--code of product-->
        <td>
          <a href="/product/<?php echo $item['id'];?>"><?php echo $item['name'];?></a>
        </td><!-- link on product -->
        <td><?php echo $item['price'] . $item['currency'];?></td><!--price-->
        <td>
          <input class="form-control amountOfGoods" data-productId="<?php echo $item['id'] ?>"
                 type="number" value="<?php echo $products[$item['id']]; ?>">
        </td><!--amount-->
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </tr>

      <tr style="border: 2px solid darkorange">
        <td colspan="3"><h4 style="color: darkorange">Общая стоимость:</h4></td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $total; ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

[image: страница изменения количества товара]

Если коротко, то в каждом поле есть количество товара, которые можно изменить.
Идея в том, что при изменении поля в js файл попадает id и количество товара.
вот js код

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
  $(".amountOfGoods").on('change', getInfo);
});

function getInfo(){
  let productId = $(this).attr('data-productId');
  let productAmount = $(this).val();

  let productInfo = {};

  productInfo[productId] = productAmount;

  console.log(productInfo);
}
```

В итоге, должен получиться ассоциативный массив вида

```
{productId : productAmount}
```

в котором хранится окончательная информация о ид товаров и их количестве.
Желаемый результат почти получен, но проблема в том, что значения попросту переписываются, таким образом хранится информация лишь об одном товаре.
метод push тут не работает.

грубо говоря нужно просто получить значения input с количеством товара и записать в массив. Неужели это никак нельзя сделать? Учтите что количество инпутов может быть разным, т.к. выводится все из базы данных...

Comment: Посмотри на это [JavaScript: основы работы с localStorage](https://ustimov.org/posts/16/)

Comment: если добавлять объект и использовать JSON.stringify то просто переписывается и ключ и значение

Comment: localstorage не решил проблему, т.к. значения все также просто перезаписываются.

Comment: При использовании localStorage.setItem(productId, productAmount); присваивается только ключ и дублируется. Значение не присваивается

Comment: а если получить предыдущее значение, добавить к нему новое и записать то что получилось?

Comment: Как вы предлагаете получить предыдущее значение?
основная проблема в том, что инпута два и поэтоу вероятно массивы и создаются разные.
видимо то что нужно сделать, сделать невозможно. Но тогда я не понимаю как в интернет магаизнах в корзине возле каждого продукта есть поле с изменением количества и оно все работает. Тут ведь по сути то же самое.

Comment: грубо говоря нужно просто записать значения инпутов с количеством товара в массив. Неужели это никак нельзя сделать?
Учтите что количество инпутов может быть разным, т.к. выводится все из базы данных...

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/238931)

Comment: в js нет ассоциативных массивов, есть объекты которые можно лишь рассматривать как массивы.

Comment: Окей. Объект как ассоциативный массв. Принял.

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем не знаю насколько правильно мое решение, но я его нашел.
Ошибка была в том, что я зациклился на атрибуте и onchange в том врмея как нужно было просто получить значения input-ов с количеством товара.
код на пхп остался без изменений.

javaScript код переделал так, чтоб при клике на кнопку изменить заказ передавать значения с input-ов с атрибутом data-productId. Вот код. Вдруг кому то тоже пригодится.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //при клике на кнопку срабатівает функция
  $("#edit").on('click', getInfo);
});

function getInfo(){


  let productsInfo = {};
  $(".amountOfGoods").each(function() {
    productsInfo[$(this).attr("data-productId")] = $(this).val();
  });

  console.log(productsInfo);
}
```

в итоге на выходе получается именно то, что было нужно.
массив типа {9: "5", 10: "3"} где первое значение - ид товара а второе - количество товара.